# write_image gets ValueError: Transform failed. Error stream

Tags: python, plotly

I have a plotly figure which I want to save as png file.
I'm trying with:

```
plotly.io.write_image(fig, "t.png", format='png')
```

And getting error:

```
ValueError: Transform failed. Error stream:
[0822/133740.955:FATAL:ipc_mojo_bootstrap.cc(729)] Check failed: message->data_num_bytes() <= Channel::kMaximumMessageSize (156938040 vs 134217728)
```

How can I save my figure ?